# Can property name be given alias

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using a 3rd party Spring Boot module that requires a `"validation.url"` property to be set

This same value exists in our centralized config service as `"url.for.validation"`, which we retrieve via a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

Outside of intercepting the Properties from the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and adding a new one for "validation.url", what is the recommended way to achieve this?

Is there any alias functionality for properties?

Comment: Just add `validation.url=${url.for.validation}` to your properties.

Comment: Hmmm...this does not work for me when I add it to application.properties

Comment: spring Boot takes care of that, you shouldn't need to add a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` with that you are actually working against the framework.

Comment: Aliasing would be useful in order to provide idiomatic environment variable names, particularly when using docker; `validation.url` looks better in Java, `VALIDATION_URL` would be better when set in a bash script.

Comment: For that last concern, you get [relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) in Spring that does that for you.